# Load Data on ComboBox MultiSelect extjs

Tags: extjs, multi-select

I have a combobox with multiselect setting for my fruits item.

so during create an user eating habit form, users are able to select multi fruits selection, my issue arise when i edit user eating habit, the form unable to display existing fruits selection.

the Display at fruits combobox
Create new user form - **Fruits Eaten: Apple,Orange**
When load previous user from should be the same result as above but instead it just display empty

part of the code in the combobox is like this

```
 {
xtype:'combobox',
fields: 'Fruits Eaten:',
editable: false,
displayField'name',
store:'FruitStore',
valueField:'name',
multiSelect:true
    }
```

for Store Model code is this

```
 Ext.define('FruitModel',{
     extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires:[
    'Ext.data.field.Field'
    ],
    fields:[
    {
    mapping:'_source.name',
    name:'name'
    },
    {
    mapping:'_source.code',
    name:'code'
    }
    ]
    });
```

the results of fruits results by elasticsearch to display the name into combobox

```
{
  "took":3,
  "timed_out":false,
  "_shards":
  {
    "total":1,
    "successful":1,
    "skipped":0,
    "failed":0
  },
  "hits":{
    "total":{
      "value":4,
      "relation":"eq"
    },
    "max_score":1.0,
    "hits":[
      {
        "_index":"fruits",
        "_type":"_doc",
        "_id":1,
        "_score":1.0,
        "_source":{
          "name":"Apple",
          "code":"AP"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"fruits",
        "_type":"_doc",
        "_id":2,
        "_score":1.0,
        "_source":{
          "name":"Orange",
          "code":"OR"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"fruits",
        "_type":"_doc",
        "_id":3,
        "_score":1.0,
        "_source":{
         "name":"Blueberry",
          "code":"BB"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"fruits",
        "_type":"_doc",
        "_id":4,
        "_score":1.0,
        "_source":{
          "name":"Pear",
          "code":"PE"
        }
      }
      ]
  }
}
```

the user form results is as below

```
{
  "took":3,
  "timed_out":false,
  "_shards":
  {
    "total":1,
    "successful":1,
    "skipped":0,
    "failed":0
  },
  "hits":{
    "total":{
      "value":4,
      "relation":"eq"
    },
    "max_score":1.0,
    "hits":[
      {
        "_index":"students",
        "_type":"_doc",
        "_id":1,
        "_score":1.0,
        "_source":{
          "name":"John",
          "fruitseaten":"Apple"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"students",
        "_type":"_doc",
        "_id":2,
        "_score":1.0,
        "_source":{
          "name":"Mary",
          "fruitseaten":"Apple,Orange"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"students",
        "_type":"_doc",
        "_id":3,
        "_score":1.0,
        "_source":{
         "name":"Karen",
          "fruitseaten":"Blueberry"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"students",
        "_type":"_doc",
        "_id":4,
        "_score":1.0,
        "_source":{
          "name":"Sam",
          "fruitseaten":"Pear"
        }
      }
      ]
  }
}
```

as what i say before for Sam, Karen and John, the combobox able to display the fruitseaten as show but for Mary the combobox value is empty and the selection is also empty

Comment: Which ExtJS version and toolkit do you use? Please include sample data.

Comment: i using EXTJS 7.1.x Classic

Comment: And how do you store this data? Multiselect combo's value will be an array.

Comment: I store it as string. issit possible to convert the value on run time to an array? but i am surprise for some records with only one fruit selection it able to display and selected

Comment: Which database do you use and what is the exact datatype of the column where you want to persist this data? Also, please give an example of `name` and `code` values for fruits.

Comment: i using elasticsearch, the datatype for that column is "text".

Comment: @PeterKoltai , i update the post with the necessary information

Comment: I see. So to be clear, you can save data even when two fruits are selected, your problem is that when you load back, it is not displayed as selected?

Comment: yes, i was able to save two or more fruits selected but the issue come when i load the user the fruitseaten with more than one fruits is not display on combobox. i not sure whether the issue come from valueField:'name',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the string value returned from your backend to an array. In your model definition for `students`, where you define `fruitseaten` field, add a `convert` function:

```
fields: [
    {
        mapping: '_source.fruitseaten',
        name: 'fruitseaten',
        convert: function(v, record) {
            return v.split(',');
        }
    },
]
```

Comment: @ngjiajun Good to hear, welcome. One more note: `multiSelect` config is [deprecated](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-multiSelect) since version 5.1.0. I suggest as per documentation to try [tagfield](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.4.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html).